# How to plot figures to different subplot axes

Tags: python, matplotlib, subplot, matplotlib-3d

I was trying to plot a figure with a combination of a 3d subplot and 3 2d ones. Why do they overlap each other?

[image]

Here are my codes:

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10,10))
ax = fig.add_subplot(3, 2, 1, projection='3d')
ax = plt.axes(projection='3d')
ax.scatter3D(extents[0], extents[1], extents[2], color='yellow')

ax = fig.add_subplot(3, 2, 2)
ax = sns.distplot(extents[0], color='red')
ax.set_title("Extent_0 Distribution")

ax = fig.add_subplot(3, 2, 4)
ax = sns.distplot(extents[1], color='blue')
ax.set_title("Extent_1 Distribution")

ax = fig.add_subplot(3, 2, 6)
ax = sns.distplot(extents[2], color='green')
ax.set_title("Extent_2 Distribution")

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- In each group, an `ax` is created with `ax = fig.add_subplot(3, 2, 1, projection='3d')`, but then you reassign the variable with `ax = plt.axes(projection='3d')`; this does not plot to `ax`.
- To plot to a specific axes, use the `ax` parameter in the plot method

  - `sns.histplot(df['freq: 1x'], ax=ax)`
- Also, upgrade seaborn to version 0.11, because `sns.distplot` is deprecated for `displot` or `histplot`.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np  # for sample data

# sinusoidal sample data
sample_length = range(1, 3+1)
rads = np.arange(0, 2*np.pi, 0.01)
data = np.array([np.sin(t*rads) for t in sample_length])
df = pd.DataFrame(data.T, index=pd.Series(rads.tolist(), name='radians'), columns=[f'freq: {i}x' for i in sample_length])

# plot the figures and correctly use the ax parameter
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10,10))
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(3, 2, 1, projection='3d')
ax1.scatter3D(df['freq: 1x'], df['freq: 2x'], df['freq: 3x'], color='green', s=5)

ax2 = fig.add_subplot(3, 2, 2)
sns.histplot(df['freq: 1x'], ax=ax2)
ax2.set_title("Extent_0 Distribution")

ax3 = fig.add_subplot(3, 2, 4)
sns.histplot(df['freq: 2x'], ax=ax3)
ax3.set_title("Extent_1 Distribution")

ax4 = fig.add_subplot(3, 2, 6)
sns.histplot(df['freq: 3x'], ax=ax4)
ax4.set_title("Extent_2 Distribution")

fig.tight_layout()
```

[image]

### Using matplotlib gridspec

- [Customizing Figure Layouts Using GridSpec and Other Functions](https://matplotlib.org/3.3.2/tutorials/intermediate/gridspec.html)
- [Tight Layout guide](https://matplotlib.org/3.3.2/tutorials/intermediate/tight_layout_guide.html#sphx-glr-tutorials-intermediate-tight-layout-guide-py)
- The size of the 3D plot can be increased by changing the number of rows, `nrows`.

  - `gs1 = fig.add_gridspec(nrows=4, ncols=3)`

```py
fig = plt.figure(constrained_layout=False, figsize=(10, 10))
gs1 = fig.add_gridspec(nrows=3, ncols=3)

ax1 = fig.add_subplot(gs1[:-1, :], projection='3d')
ax1.scatter3D(df['freq: 1x'], df['freq: 2x'], df['freq: 3x'], color='green', s=10)

ax2 = fig.add_subplot(gs1[-1, 0])
sns.histplot(df['freq: 1x'], kde=True, ax=ax2)
ax2.set_title("Extent_0 Distribution")

ax3 = fig.add_subplot(gs1[-1, 1])
sns.histplot(df['freq: 2x'], kde=True, ax=ax3)
ax3.set_title("Extent_1 Distribution")

ax4 = fig.add_subplot(gs1[-1, 2])
sns.histplot(df['freq: 3x'], kde=True, ax=ax4)
ax4.set_title("Extent_2 Distribution")

plt.tight_layout()
```

[image]